# Getting invalid_grant on reddit auth api reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api, reddit

```
const query = {
    method: method,
    url: uri,
    auth: {
      username: 'uxxxQxxxMxxx7w',
      password: 'xxxxX9xxxxxxxx'
  },
```

hey i am getting invalid_grant error in my response.please help me or guide me to the right process if i am going wrong.

Comment: Are you retrieving access token?

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving `grant_type` in your request as `'grant_type' => 'password'`

```
const query = {
   method: method,
   url: uri,
   auth: {
     grant_type: 'password',
     username: 'uxxxQxxxMxxx7w',
     password: 'xxxxX9xxxxxxxx'
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add grant_type=authorizatio_code in the query parameter

```
var options = {
    method: "POST",
    url:"https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code&code="+req.query.code+"&redirect_uri=uri",
    auth: {
        user: "************",
        password:"****************"
          }
```